# put a row in a <p> tag from a nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-loops

I need to append a triangle shape in `html` page also I need to put every row in a `p tag` to check if its even or odd

```
var line = '<p class = odd>'
  var l = " ";
  var myDiv = $('<div id = "container"></div>')
  $('body').append(myDiv)
  var randColor = '#' +(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

  for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= input-i ; j++) {
    $('#container').css('color',randColor)

    $("#container").append( line + i);
    }
    $("#container").append(l);
  }
```

Comment: You could use a nth-child psudoselector instead

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
var line = '<p class = odd>'
var l = "</p>";
var myDiv = $('<div id = "container"></div>')
$('body').append(myDiv)
var randColor = '#' +(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
var str="";
for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j <= input-i ; j++) {
     str+=i;
  }
}

$("#container").append( line + str+l);
```

Comment: Does not work it stills put every number in a p tag @Atikur Rahman